# Laravel: calling multiple methods on one object instance

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I'm relatively new to laravel and oop, by no means an expert, so I can't wrap my head around some things involving facades.

Let's say I'm building a class to interact with API to create new shipment labels for my ecommerce orders. The class can post data to the API for creating new shipments and has some properties (adress to ship to, email of my client for track and trace code etc...) and methods (creating new shipment, get price returned by API, etc...). The name of the class will be Shipment.

In vanilla php i would do something like:

```
$shipment = new shipment()
$shipment->create($data)
$price = $shipment->getPrice()
```

But in laravel I'd like to use facades. So I created my shipment facade and registered a service provider that returns a new shipment with a 'shipment' binding. Now I know if I do

```
Shipment::create($data)
```

laravel will actually do

```
$app->['shipment']->create($data)
```

And now comes my misunderstanding.  If I now do a Shipment::getPrice(), will laravel create another instance of the shipment class, or will it use the same instance that was created on Shipment::create() ?

I do want to continue to use the first instance to acces the shipment object properties (which are filled with data that is returned from the API) and not create a new instance of the shipping class since the properties of a new class would still be empty without calling the create method first!

Do I need to do

```
$shipment = Shipment::create()
```

and then acces the getPrice method via

```
$shipment->getPrice()
```

or is this the wrong way to do it and is there a better, more "laravel/OOP" way?

To rephrase my question: How do I continue calling methods on an object after it's intstanciated via a facade/IoC binding, without creating new instances on subsequent calls? And vice versa, if I do demoClass::randomMethod via a facade for multiple times, will every time a new demoClass be instanciated?

Thousend times thanks in advance!!

Comment: your create method, does it create an object? it kind of makes answering hard. try and choose better name maybe fill ?

Comment: It doesn't create an object no, it only talks to an API and fill the objects properties with the response from the API. So I need to use the same instance when using those methods. But if I want to create another shipping I want to create a new instance and calling the methods again on that instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use facades you will always get the same instance of object.

If you bind your class using:

```
App::bind('shipment', function()
    {
        return new \Shipment\Shipment;
    });
```

Have facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Shipment extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'shipment'; }

}
```

and your class:

```
namespace Shipment;

class Shipment {

    private $data;

    public function create($data) {
        $this->data[] = $data;
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return implode(' ',$this->data);
    }
}
```

you can run simply:

```
Shipment::create('something');

Shipment::create('something2');

echo Shipment::getPrice();
```

And you will get as output

```
something something2
```

because this class saves data in array and get you imploded data. As you see you don't need to create any extra variables because you operate on the same object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But if I'm right I tought that to use the same instance every time you need to do App::singleton(). If you do App:bind() I thought it would return a new instance on every facade call?

Comment: @LuukVanDongen It will return the same object instance. As you see in above example. If it hasn't, result would be different. Now you set some value to object twice in 2 different calls, and in 3rd call you get their value, so the object has to be the same.

Comment: So every time I use a facade I thought laravel would do app->make[object]->method. So every time a new object should be instanciated. Or will laravel search for existing objects with the same name if a facade is used and call the methods on that object instead of creating a new one?

Comment: @LuukVanDongen As you see in above example it won't create new object. It will use the same object

Comment: But then what is the difference between app::bind and app::singleton? Since both return one and the same object?